# Android image inside linear layout not working properly

Tags: android, imageview, background-image, android-linearlayout

Hi I am developing small android application in which I am displaying image view inside linear layout. The problem is that it is not showing any image until I set background colour for my linear layout. I tried it in following way:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/action_button_llt"
android:layout_width="@dimen/user_profile_edit_view_dim"
android:layout_height="@dimen/user_profile_edit_view_dim"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_8"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_3"
android:layout_gravity="right">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/action_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
</LinearLayout>

// set icon programatically ... 
        action_img.setImageDrawable(icon);

 public void setAction(String action, Drawable icon)
{
    this.action = action;
    action_img.setImageDrawable(icon);
}

        profileCardView.setAction("edit_profile",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_icon_white));
```

above layout not showing anything. But if I set background colour for my linear layout it shows icon as well as linear layout also. Am I doing anything wrong?Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code around where you set `action_img.setImageDrawable(icon);`?

Comment: Are you possibly initializing your app calling `setContentView` after doing this `setAction`?

Comment: try this one `action_img.setImageResource(icon);`